Calculate distance between numerous points and one specific point using Point Distance in 4326 projection In ArcMap
I'm using the WGS1984 projection since it's the required projection in my class, as a result, I can't accurately calculate the distance between one point and other points since the output data will turn into numbers according to the Geographical Coordinate System. I understand that I need to use a Local Coordinate System for the Linear units but I don't have a choice. Is there a work around for this?

reproject your data to calculate to correct distance.

Point Distance is deprecated. Use Near, and you have a GEODESIC parameter available.

If you want to use the (deprecated) Point Distance tool, you will have to reproject your data (this will create some temporary layers you can delete afterwards and your original data will remain in WGS84).  If you use the Near tool instead, there is a "method" parameter that you can set to "geodesic" which will allow you to calculate distance correctly with a geographic coordinate system.
